# systemd network issues, ' code=exited, status=1/FAILURE'

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemd-networkd, vps

I have an application that fails to connect with networking
(that's what I assume) and throws a `code=exited, status=1/FAILURE` error
if I start it using systemd. 
However, if I start that application manually, everything works fine. 
Also I tested the same exact service on a different VPS provider
and everything worked fine. 
Both use Ubuntu 20.04 operational system. 
What could be causing this issue?

That's the last output I get before it turns off.

```
[INFO] Initializing networking...
[ERROR] Networking failed to start.  Terminating..
```

This is my `.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=yesyes
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/opt/srv
ExecStart=/opt/srv/ragemp-server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: How do you get the output? By using `systemctl status` or `journalctl`? With those commands you can get a more detailed log about your error.